# Trouble with SQLite : Query Error: near FROM: syntax error Unable to execute statement

Tags: sqlite, syntax

I keep getting this error in SQLite:

> Query Error: near "FROM": syntax error Unable to execute statement

```
SELECT Name, CourseId
    FROM Lecturer JOIN Lecture ON Lecturer.LecturerId = Lecture.LecturerId
    JOIN     (SELECT CourseId   
        FROM Course
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM Exam
                WHERE Exam.CourseId = Course.CourseId
                AND (SELECT COUNT *
                          FROM Exam
                          WHERE Grade > 6)
                <
                (SELECT COUNT *
                FROM Exam
                WHERE Grade < 6)))
    USING Course.Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally assign the inline view an alias, e.g FOO, and join an outer table to the inline view with an on... clause:

```
  select * from x
  join
  (
      select someColumn, someOtherColumn...

  ) as FOO
  on x.somecolumn = FOO.somecolumn
```

I would go about it this way:

```
  select lecture.*, FOO.courseid
  from lecture
  join lecturer on lecture.lecturerid = lecturer.lecturerid
  join
  (
       you inline view selecting the courses

  ) as FOO
  on lecture.courseid = FOO.courseid
```

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` is a function, you need parens around the `*`

Such as:

`COUNT(*)`